# Angular API date not working: timestamp from PHP backend needs to be refactored?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, timestamp, angular-filters

I am having no luck using Angular's date API. Someone else who is no longer working on this app wrote the backend in PHP and the Database is mySql..

I think that the original `timestamp` that's being used on the backend perhaps does "not play nice" with Angular's date API and I was wondering if from what I am showing you someone could suggest that, perhaps, "Yes!" Indeed the way we are storing date and time in our backend and db is what's causing Angular not to display the  date format we want.

I did a search in the PHP code and I found the following and I was wondering if this is where I should change the timestamp.. Or do I have the completely wrong approach to this?

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/myapp.sql:

  140    `car_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  141    `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  142:   `driver_departing_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  143    `driver_arrival_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  144    `departing_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you store dates in database should not matter. What is important is way in which the application communicates with the server. For example, if it's using a REST service, you should check what date format is required by service requests and format date properly either on the client or on the server side.

I'm not familiar with PHP so I won't tell you how to check that in code. However, you can use browser development tools (e.g. Network tab in Google Chrome) to check format in which server sends dates. Then, you can format them properly on the client side with Moment.js library or by using any other method.